# PouchDB - Map/Reduce similer to SQL group by?

Tags: pouchdb

Consider following sample docs stored in pouchdb.

```
{
  "_id": "milk-20190509T010751.826-1",
  "animal": "B",
  "shift": "M",
  "ltr": 5,
  "code": 1,
  "custName": "Balvant Jat",
  "type": "milk",
  "netAmt": 200,
  "billName": "1951",
}

{
  "_id": "milk-20190509T010751.827-1",
  "animal": "B",
  "shift": "M",
  "ltr": 6,
  "code": 1,
  "custName": "Balvant Jat",
  "type": "milk",
  "netAmt": 150,
  "billName": "1951",
}

{
  "_id": "milk-20190509T010751.828-2",
  "animal": "B",
  "shift": "M",
  "ltr": 6,
  "code": 2,
  "custName": "Ashvin Jat",
  "type": "milk",
  "netAmt": 500,
  "billName": "1951",
}
```

I have tried some map/reduce function and also used `group:true` option but could not get expected result. I tried map function as below

```
mapFunc = (doc) => {
   if(doc.type === 'milk'){
   emit(doc.billName,{code:doc.code,name:doc.name,ltr:doc.ltr,amount:doc.netAmt})
   }
}
```

but no idea about reduce function where I stopped.

I want to be resulting document like below.

```
{
  "code": 1,
  "custName": "Balvant Jat",
  "totalLtr": 11 
  "totalNetAmt": 350,
}

{
  "code": 2,
  "custName": "Ashvin Jat",
  "totalLtr": 6
  "totalNetAmt": 500,
}
```